# Upload Bulk Image in MultipuleThread android

Tags: android, multithreading, image-uploading, bulkloader

right now i am uploading image in single thread using asynctask. but it is not efficient and it's takes lot of time to upload. so i am refering this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html) to download image using ThreadPoolExecuter. can i use this strategy while uploading image also ?

is this good practice to upload image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this good practice to upload image?

YES that could be an option if you don't worry about tracking of each execution (i.e when thread completed its task ).

See what [google doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) says

> they usually provide improved performance when executing large numbers
>   of asynchronous tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead,
>   and they provide a means of bounding and managing the resources,
>   including threads, consumed when executing a collection of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can down- as well as up-load an image in a separate thread, that's perfectly fine.

If you want to use several threads for that, it would make no sense due to limited bandwidth (several threads would not speed-up the process) and partitioning issues (on the server).

Comment: so according to you . there is no need to create multiple Thread for it. single Background Thread using IntentService Solve This issue even if there is and more than 50 images ??

Comment: The critical factor here is the IO bandwidth. Even with HSDPA (LTE is not everywhere available) you can upload 1 image at a time. So, even if you create and start 50 threads for 50 images, they all get queued (due to IO-locking), which returns us effectively to 1 thread per 50 images. You can also use `Loaders` from the google doc link you posted

Comment: I would completely disagree with this assessment.  Depending on the nature/size/compression of the image, multithreaded upload may speed things up 2-10x.  It is rare that your IO is slower than your network.  (currently I am uploading >50,000 120MB images to s3, and threading really speeds things up)  More evidence [here](http://improve.dk/pushing-the-limits-of-amazon-s3-upload-performance/)

Comment: so, did this speed the things up?

Comment: yup i try it on my Project And It Works Radically Fast .